# surf to a web page through console in java

Tags: java, networking, html

I wonder is it possible to write a console application that will surf to a web page without opening a browser? I want to check if a web page is alive (and check for an HTML string in it), but I don't want to open a web browser every time for this since I have a great number of web pages to check. What is the best way to go about this? I have some knowledge in java but not so much in networking with java.

any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [java.net.URL.getConnection()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29):

```
InputStream is = null;
try{
    URL page = new URL("http://example.com/");
    URLConnection connection = page.openConnection();
    is = connection.getInputStream();
}
catch(MalformedURLException e)
{
    // ....
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    // Couldn't connect to website
}
// do something with input stream
```

Comment: This are internal company servers that I want to check, can i use IP addresses instead of the url addresses?

Comment: @user811195: According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html "host can be expressed as a host name or a literal IP address. If IPv6 literal address is used, it should be enclosed in square brackets ('[' and ']'), as specified by RFC 2732; However, the literal IPv6 address format defined in RFC 2373: IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture is also accepted"

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've tried changing the host part of the url to an ip address but when I run the program I get "protocol = http host = null" exception.

I'm writing the url like this:

 "URL oracle = new URL("http:\\10.200.10.199");

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably. because `\\ ` should be `//`.

Comment: Stupidddddd meeee!!! It works great now! Now I only need to search for a particular string in this url in order to confirm the webpage exists.

Answer (score 1):

You might give this short tutorial a try: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Also you will find more code samples here: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/pkg.html